# Measure the total height of elements with same class

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is it possible to measure the total height of a group of elements which have the same class?

I have the following code:

```html
<ul class="wrapper">
  <li class="row-1">
    <a>This is row 1</a>
  </li>
  <li class="row-1">
    <a>This is row 1</a>
  </li>
  <li class="row-1">
    <a>This is row 1</a>
  </li>
  <li class="row-1">
    <a>This is row 1</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I want to know what the combined height of all the `row-1` elements. I can't use the height of the container because there could be other elements in there which I am not interested in knowing the height of.

Comment: You can run in a loop over the 'row-1' elements and sum their height.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var height = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.wrapper .row-1')).map(el => el.clientHeight).reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get all the elements by using `document.getElementsByClassName('row-1')` and then loop over them, getting the height of each element at each iteration and then adding that to a total variable (`totalHeight`).

In the snippet, I've also provided a way to achieve this using ES6's `reduce` method, where you can achieve the same output in one line:

See the snippet below for a working example:

```js
let rows = document.getElementsByClassName("row-1"); // Get all the elements with the class "row-1"
let totalHeight = 0; // Set an accumulator variable to `0`
for(let i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) { // Loop through each element with the class "row-1"
  totalHeight += rows[i].offsetHeight; // Add the height of the element to the accumulator variable (the total)
}
console.log(totalHeight); // Output the total height to the console

// ES6 way:
console.log(Array.prototype.reduce.call(rows, (acc, elem) => acc + elem.offsetHeight, 0));
```

```html
<ul class="wrapper">
  <li class="row-1">
    <a>This is row 1</a>
  </li>
  <li class="row-1">
    <a>This is row 1</a>
  </li>
  <li class="row-1">
    <a>This is row 1</a>
  </li>
  <li class="row-1">
    <a>This is row 1</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

* Note I have used `.offsetHeight` which includes the height, vertical padding, and vertical borders. You can use other height measurements such as `.clientHeight`

Answer (score 1):

There is simple solution exist in jquery. Just use `height()` method on every `row-1` element. The `each` function will iterate on all the elements of given class and returns final height.

```js
var height = 0;
$(".row-1").each(function() {
  height += $(this).height();
});
console.log(height);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="wrapper">
  <li class="row-1">
   <a>This is row 1</a>
  </li>
  <li class="row-1">
   <a>This is row 1</a>
  </li>
  <li class="row-1">
   <a>This is row 1</a>
  </li>
  <li class="row-1">
   <a>This is row 1</a>
  </li>
 </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  var height = 0;
  $.each( $(".row-1"), function( key, value ) {
     height += $(value).height();
  });

  console.log(height);
});
```

```html
<html>

    <head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<ul class="wrapper">
  <li class="row-1">
    <a>This is row 1</a>
  </li>
  <li class="row-1">
    <a>This is row 1</a>
  </li>
  <li class="row-1">
    <a>This is row 1</a>
  </li>
  <li class="row-1">
    <a>This is row 1</a>
  </li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```